# Copy and paste cell with a certain text

Tags: excel, vba

I want to fill my entire table with the description related to a specific opt.

At the start I have a table that looks like this:

```
Product     |OPT    |    DESC_EN                 |    DESC_ITA  
____________________________________________________________________
red car     |a      |    en description opt a    |    NULL  
white car   |a      |    en description opt a    |    it description opt a          
green car   |a      |    en description opt a    |    NULL          
red car     |b      |    en description opt b    |    NULL          
green car   |b      |    en description opt b    |    it description opt b  
red car     |c      |    en description opt c    |    NULL          
white car   |c      |    en description opt c    |    NULL          
green car   |c      |    en description opt c    |    it description opt c
```

I'm missing some translations in the last column of the table. As the description refers to the option and not to the product itself, I can take the same description from another product with the same opt.

Example:
The white car has the Italian description for *opt a*.
I can take the description from *opt a* of the white car and use it for *opt a* of the red car.
The same with the green car and so on.

In the end my table will look like this:

```
 Product    |OPT    |    DESC_EN                 |    DESC_ITA  
____________________________________________________________________
red car     |a      |    en description opt a    |    it description opt a      
white car   |a      |    en description opt a    |    it description opt a          
green car   |a      |    en description opt a    |    it description opt a          
red car     |b      |    en description opt b    |    it description opt b          
green car   |b      |    en description opt b    |    it description opt b  
red car     |c      |    en description opt c    |    it description opt c          
white car   |c      |    en description opt c    |    it description opt c          
green car   |c      |    en description opt c    |    it description opt c
```

```vb
Sub Test3()
    Dim Var As String
    Dim found As Boolean
    Dim row_number As Integer
    Dim col_number As Integer
  
    Var = "NULL"
    found = False
    cRow = 1
    cCol = 0
  
    Range("B2").Select
    Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
    
        If Cells(cRow, 3) = Var Then
            found = True
        
            'here is where i should copy and paste the value
        
            Exit Do
        End If
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        cRow = cRow + 1
    Loop
  
    If found = True Then
        MsgBox "Value found "
    Else
        MsgBox "Value not found"
    End If

End Sub
```

How do I take the value from the cell that has the translation for an opt and paste it in the cell where the translation is missing for that opt?

I made a Boolean variable to check if my code gets the right value and it should so the only thing missing is copying the description into the cell that matches the opt.

Answer (score -2):

You've got some logical errors in your code here. For starters you've redefined your variable "Var" as empty string ("") on line 8 instead of "NULL". So your if condition isn't checking for "NULL" it's checking for empty string. I would rename this variable too so it's more readable.

Secondly, that "Exit Do" will jump out of the loop as soon as the condition is met (ActiveCell == "NULL") so you probably want that removed.

Lastly, your indexes are off by 1: Rows and Columns start at index 1 for their first member. For example, Cells(1,1) would be of value "Product".

*Edit* - Sorry forgot one more thing. When you're doing string comparisons it's always good to [TRIM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/ltrim-rtrim-and-trim-functions) your input of whitespace. In this case the inputs are the cells.

Comment: firstly i've deleted the second var that was named Var bcs it was a misstypo. Secondly I've made that exit do to try to catch if my variable is read and understand by the code and at least it will copy one translation if the code i made will work.... By third, the column is remaining the same as you can see in the loop clause so i don't need to have my indexes alligned!

Comment: @Repsss - Regarding the indexes you've got `cCol = 0` on line 10. I was assuming this variable was going to keep track of a column index like `cRow` is. If you don't intend to use `cCol` I recommend removing it. Further, this if condition: `If Cells(cRow, 3) = Var Then` does not look right to me. Just above the this if statement if you write `MsgBox Cells(cRow, 3)` you will get a cell value from you DESC_EN column. Based on your requirements, DESC_ITA is the column you want to check if is "NULL". That would be column 4.